# What is `set -o keyword` doing on bash?

Tags: bash, set

What function exactly is the "**keyword**" option assigned by the `set` command on bash shell?

### OPTION:

`set -o keyword`

OR

`set -k`

A simple example is enough for me to understand.

Comment: `help set` tells you that they are equivalent.

Comment: @Panki You misunderstood the question. I didn't ask the difference, I know they both mean the same thing. You dropped points for nothing, I just mentioned both options so that people who would search either way later would find it easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually, to inject an environment variable for a command, you place an assignment to a name before the command like this:

```
VARIABLE=value bash -c 'echo "$1 $VARIABLE"' bash hello
```

This runs `bash -c 'echo "$VARIABLE"' bash hello` and sets `VARIABLE` to the string `value` in the environment of that command.  The command, in this case will, print `hello value` (with `hello` coming from the in-line script's first command line argument, and `value` coming from the environment variable).

With `set -o keyword` (or `set -k`) in `bash` (this is a non-standard shell option), the assignment is allowed to occur anywhere on the command line:

```
$ set -k
$ bash -c 'echo "$1 $VARIABLE"' bash hello VARIABLE=value
hello value
$ bash -c 'echo "$1 $VARIABLE"' bash VARIABLE=value hello
hello value
$ bash -c 'echo "$1 $VARIABLE"' VARIABLE=value bash hello
hello value
$ bash -c VARIABLE=value 'echo "$1 $VARIABLE"' bash hello
hello value
$ bash VARIABLE=value -c 'echo "$1 $VARIABLE"' bash hello
hello value
```

I've never seen this option used "in the wild" and I'm assuming that it's only used sparingly under very specific circumstances, as it radically changes the way commands are parsed.

Answer (score 3):

From the manual:

> -k
>
> > All arguments in the form of assignment statements are placed in the environment for a command, not just those that precede the command name.

With some experimentation:

```bsh
$ bash -c '
    env | grep -e foo -e baz
    for ((i=0; i<=$#; i++)); do echo "$i = ${!i}"; done
' foo=bar baz=qux
```

```
0 = foo=bar
1 = baz=qux
```

The var=val arguments are plain parameters.

But with `set -o keyword`

```bsh
$ set -k
$ bash -c '
    env | grep -e foo -e baz
    for ((i=0; i<=$#; i++)); do echo "$i = ${!i}"; done
' foo=bar baz=qux
```

```
foo=bar
baz=qux
0 = bash
```

The var=val arguments are detected, removed from the parameters, and put in the environment.

Answer (score -1):

`set -o keyword` allows to set one of the binary bash options defined by "keyword" where you need to replace "keyword" by the actual option name, for instance it can be replaced by xtrace as shown below

these options take 2 values on or off, for instance `set -o xtrace` will turn tracing on

to reset this option use `set +o xtrace`

the list of all options settings can be get by omitting the keyword `set -o` whereas `set +o` shows an alternate view of the list of options settings
listing all options give you the name of all the options names to be used instead of "keyword"

`set -k` is an option by itself used to alter the environment assignment syntax and is described in the other answers

Comment: You misunderstood stand the question. `keyword` itself is the name of an option, like the `xtrace` you mention.

Comment: answer improved to remove possible confusion between the actual word "keyword" and what it stands for